# Merging annotations in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, merge, annotation

[image]

How do I merge two annotations into a single part?

Comment: I think you'll need to copy the content from one into the other (without deleting the existing content in that other) and then delete the one you copied from.  I have not tested this.

Comment: Just i want merge like how polygons merged

Comment: When you tried doing it like that did it work, or what precisely happened?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Are there two records, or is this just one multipart annotation text?

Comment: Ya two records.